# My soap produces less lather as it gets old

Tags: everyday-life, water, physical-chemistry

I don't know it you have encountered this too but I have observed this "phenomenon" from the last few hundred soaps I have used. 
As the soaps get older they produce less lather than they produced when they were new. Why is this?
My guesses are

1. The surface area of the soap decreases as the soap gets used?
2. Due to the hardness of the water?

Any other reasons you can think of?

Answer (score 1):

I too have experienced this ever since first having to purchase my own soap supplies. I suspect that this is because the surface of the sliver of soap has become enriched in the products of the reaction between hardness chemicals in the water and the soap molecules, which inhibits foaming. My experimental evidence is as follows:

Upon accumulating a convenient number of these poorly-foaming slivers, I would crush them into a coarse powder by hand and glue that powder with spit into a (small) bar of soap mix which I would then allow to dry. This bar of "spit soap" seemed to recover the foaming nature of the soap bars from which the slivers had formed.

I last prepared spit soap 49 years ago, but it shouldn't be too difficult to devise a controlled experiment to see if this effect can be reproduced with modern methods.

Comment: Clever experiment, but how about just scraping or sanding the surface layer off the soap?

Comment: there are recipies n how to make new soap out of slivers and I did last year., one of them https://www.instructables.com/id/Reforming-Soap-Scraps/ . I think it is the water (in your case the spit) that increases foam. Actually, when I buy new soap I open it and leave it for some weeks to the air so that it dries out and does not become icky  when used, then it also makes less bubbles, but it is not the bubbles that clean